# Transform 1-D x, y, z vectors into 2D mesh grid

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, 2d

I have spatial data set that are initially in 3 columns of data - x, y, z

Please run this code and see how the data looks like.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[50. , 50. ,  0.3],
       [55. , 25. , -1.5],
       [ 6.6, 47.4,  0.1],
       [35. , 34.9,  1. ],
       [32.7, 56.3,  1.9]]), columns=['x', 'y', 'z'])

x = data['x']
y = data['y']
z = data['z']

def plot_sparse(x, y, z, ax, dist_max, **kwargs):

    assert len(x) == len(y) == len(z), "x, y, and z must have the same dimension"

    sc = ax.scatter(x, y, c=z, **kwargs)
    ax.set_aspect("equal")
    ax.set_xlim(0, dist_max)
    ax.set_ylim(0, dist_max)

    return sc

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sc = plot_sparse(x, y, z, ax=ax, dist_max=80)
fig.colorbar(sc)
```

I want to replicate the figure generated using meshgrid:

```
[X, Y] = np.meshgrid(x, y)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sc = ax.scatter(x, y)
ax.set_aspect("equal")
ax.set_xlim(0, 80)
ax.set_ylim(0, 80)
```

But I do not know how to embed values of z-axis into mesh grid. The above code using meshgrid will not have a color bar on a 2D surface plot, but I want to make color bar using meshgrid data type.

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you want to draw a scatter plot or an image plot?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I would like to have it on image plot

Comment: Ok, so this means that your data needs to lie on a rectilinear (call it rectangular if you wish) grid. But the coordinates you have are pretty random. So what should be the value at the positions in the image where you don't have any data points?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I thought the values were provided? `data['z']` is the value column. have you run the first block of my codes?

Comment: Yes. But now you want an image. How do you imagine this to look like in terms of the coordinates? [This is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Mvlz.png) what I would imagine to be an image of your data. Is this what you want? Seems not very useful. So best describe clearly how your data relates to what you want to see in the plot.

Comment: There was a question exactly like this just a while ago. The main point here is that if you have N x-values and N y-values, you will need NxN z-values in order to be able to use `np.meshgrid`.